# Completeness of discrete shifts in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

Consider the space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Let $(x_n)_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence and $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ a functions. It is well understood under which assumptions the span of the set
$$
S = \{ f(\cdot - x_n) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This goes into the theory of generators of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, one can show that if $f$ is a Gaussian then we can find a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that the span of $S$ is dense.

Can this be generalized to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ where $d > 1$? In this case, $(x_n)_n$ would be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it again possible to choose $f$ to be a Gaussian? So far, I didn't find results on this question in the literature.

Comment: Fourier transform everything and use density in $L^2$ of functions whose Fourier transform is $C_c^\infty$. It shouldn't be hard to prove then.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. How does the density of functions with smooth and compactly supported Fourier transform helps me here?

Comment: If you fourier transform, the shifts of a Gaussian become multiplications of a Gaussian by functions $\exp(i\xi\cdot x)$. By density, we only need to approximate $C_c^\infty$ functions. Let $g$ be such a function, and say that we are trying to approximate it within $\epsilon$ in $L^2$. Take a big box of large side length $R$, on that box use Fourier series to approximate $g/f$ well. Hopefully your errors outside of the box will be small, since $f$ decays very quickly. Obviously it will take some work to bound all the errors.

Comment: If you only need one sequence, let me finish the argument for people who don't like to bound errors. I choose the image of the sequence to be all of $\mathbb Z^d$. The density of $C^\infty_c$ shows that functions of the form $gf$ for $g$ bounded, smooth, $(k\mathbb Z)^d$-periodic for some $k\in\mathbb N$, are dense; indeed, for $h\in C^\infty_c$, take the $2k$-periodic function $g_k$ that coincides with $g/f$ on $[-k,k]^d$. Such periodic $g$ are uniform limits of trigonometric polynomials (usual Fourier series), so $gf$ are $L^2$-limits of the set of functions described by Sam.

Comment: What is the theorem that everyone seems to be referring here? Given a function (with an assumption) how do you get the sequence $(x_n)$ so that $f(\cdot-x_n$'s are dense in $L_2$? I am aware of Olevskii's theorem (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0764444297878731) but you seem to be referring to something else.

Comment: One result which is somehow designed for Gaussians is due to Zalik, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305874521_On_approximation_by_shifts_and_a_theorem_of_Wiener , Theorem 2